# Generate Update query to Update a table with a simmilar table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

Generate Update query to Update a table with a simmilar table i am using this Query

```
select '
update LT_Status_test1  
Set StatusName='''+ T.StatusName+''' 
where StatusID=CONVERT(varchar(max),'''+T.StatusID+''') 
from  LT_Status_test T'
```

It gives  error

> The multi-part identifier "T.StatusName" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "T.StatusID" could not be bound.

Need help...or any kind of suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You need an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE LT_Status_test1
SET LT_Status_test1.StatusName = LT_Status_test.StatusName
FROM LT_Status_test1
JOIN LT_Status_test
    ON LT_Status_test.StatusID = LT_Status_test1.StatusID
```